# Use delegates in place of typedef in C#

Tags: c#, c++, class, delegates, typedef

In C++, I have the following code:

```
class Card
{
    public:
        typedef void (*FunctType)(std::vector<Card> &KaibaHand, std::vector<Card> &KaibaDeck, std::vector< std::vector<Card> > &Field);   
    FunctType GetEffect();
    void SetEffect(FunctType setEffect);

private:
    FunctType Effect;
}
```

and later on in the Main() function, I'm able to call GetEffect with the following line

```
Card::FunctType effect = Field[0][TrapSlot-1].GetEffect();
(*effect) (KaibaHand, KaibaDeck, Field);
```

I'm not sure how to do this in C#. I read about how function pointers are replaced with Degelates. I tried below but got the error "The type or namespace name 'DelEffect' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
class Card
{
    void effect(List<Card> KaibaHand, List<Card> KaibaDeck, List< List<Card> > Field);   

public delegate void DelEffect(List<Card> KaibaHand, List<Card> KaibaDeck, List<List<Card>> Field);
    public void Effect
    {
        get { return effect; }
        set { effect = value; }
    }
}
```

and in the Main function

```
DelEffect e1 = new DelEffect(Effect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Action<>` for *void functions* and `Func<>` when function *returns a value*:

```
// Action can be used as a shorter from of delegate 
public Action<List<Card>, List<Card>, List<List<Card>>> Effect {
  get;
  set;
}

...

// Function
private void effect(List<Card> KaibaHand, 
                    List<Card> KaibaDeck, 
                    List<List<Card>> Field) {
  ... 
}

...

Effect = effect;
...

List<Card> KaibaHand = ... 
List<Card> KaibaDeck = ...
List<List<Card>> Field = ...

// If function Effect is specified call it:
if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, Effect)) {
  Effect(KaibaHand, KaibaDeck, Field);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Func<> Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Action<> Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(if your method return void):

In your case it will look like:

```
class Card
{
    public Action<List<Card>, List<Card>, List<Card>> Effect { get; set; }
}
```